# Refactor CSS Class reseletor

Tags: css

How do i refactor the following CSS class selector?

```
.second-panel .k-block, 
.second-panel .k-header, 
.second-panel .k-grid-header,
.second-panel .k-toolbar, 
.second-panel .k-grouping-header, 
.second-panel .k-pager-wrap,
.second-panel .k-draghandle 
 {
background-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/edegef/1/edit)

```
.second-panel *[class^="k-"] {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Again, If you have an exception of just 1-2 elements you can use `:not` selector to avoid giving them the following styles.

Example:[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/edegef/3/edit)

```
.second-panel *[class^="k-"]:not(.k-noapply):not(.k-noapply2) {
   background-color: red;
}
```

But I would suggest considering this as last option. Because if number of such elements increase, you end up doing what is actually written in the question. So you can do it for just 1-2 elements.

Comment: i have other k- matching that i don't want to apply background: red;

Comment: Best practice for this should be: Define a new class with name red and style for this would be background-color: red. Add this class to those  elements on which you want to add red backgroud. Does it make sense ?

Comment: If you want to define multiple properties apart from background-color consider defining a new class with a name which makes sense to clasify this group of elements and define the properties. This kind of solution is quite scalable.

Comment: ya, understand that but add class to the specific div is not an options for me because the html are generated, i have no access to modify what's generated.

Comment: You can use `:not` selector only if the number of elements on which you do not want to add red background is quite less like 1 or 2.